# trailblazer issue

Tags: starting

My son replaced battery in 2002 trailblazer about 2 months ago. He just replaced the alternator in it today. The car started for him and he drove to his destination about 5 minutes away. Now it will not start even with a jump. When he turns the key over the radio comes on and he gets the dings but it will not turn over. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the engine physically turn over but not start, or does it just "click" and not turn over at all. If the battery has insufficient charge, then perhaps the alternator was bad. If charge is good, perhaps the starter is bad

Comment: I would start by removing the battery and charge it. Then clean battery posts and cables. Then clean the cables that connect to the starter. Then clean the other end of negative battery cable connection. Then make sure the alternator cables are clean. Then put the fully charged battery in the vehicle. If it still don't work, you now have a starting point for diagnosis.

Comment: It could be the anti theft is active.